# Derivative of $\left\lvert y \right\rvert $ = $x^2$ with respect to x.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, quadratics

Pretty straight forward question that I need help with (This is part of a bigger question where |y|= $x^2$ is a curve, for which the tangent at a given point is to be found).
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Usually, we speak of the derivative of a map. What is the map here? $\lvert y \rvert$ is not the definition of a map.

Comment: @Alv I tried substituting |y|= u and got du = 2x.dx but I can't proceed after that.

Comment: @CapHimYT Try to include your attempt in your question as well. Here is the tutorial to [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite $\left| y \right|$ as $\sqrt{y^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got $\frac {dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{2x|y|}{y}$

Comment: To @CapHimYT: You're welcome! Next time, try to show more research effort in your Q(s)!